# disabling default button or enter key in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a form where users scan in a barcode, the barcode reader automatically enters a carriage return in the value causing the form to submit since the browser chooses the first button as the default. How can I disable anything from happening when the enter key is pressed when entring a value in that textbox?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll need to do it with javascript.  In your markup for the text box, add an onkeydown handler like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
   onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);" >
</asp:TextBox>
```

This will return false if the key was the enter key, which will cancel the form submission.

Answer (score 4):

Set the TextBox to have the text mode property set to "multiline". Then the carriage return will be in the TextBox.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230/enter-key-to-insert-newline-in-asp-net-multiline-textbox-control) for a note about what to do if you're using FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void textbox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
```

// do nothing

```
        }
    }
```

this may help you

Comment: That would work fine if this was Windows Forms - alas, it's ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

handle the onkeypress event and do something like this

```
 if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
 {
     // set event handled
     e.Handled = true;
 }
```

Comment: Alas, no OnKeyPress event, as this is ASP.NET.

Comment: the javascript answer should work.  Here's a thread that explains why these events aren't available: http://aspadvice.com/forums/thread/27557.aspx

Kind of obvious if you think about it.