# ASP.Net page enter key causing post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have an aspx page that postsback when it should not. there are two text boxes, two listboxes and two buttons on the page. if at any-point the enter key is pressed the first button is given focus and "clicked" resulting in a loss of selection within the listboxes.

How do I disable this? There are tons of tutorials on how to capture the enter button and execute a method but I could not find one on how to simply disable the neat "let me grab the first button I find and click it" feature mentioned above.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934223/disabling-default-button-or-enter-key-in-asp-et-c-sharp

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- You could set the [DefaultButton](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx&rct=j&q=defaultbutton%20asp.net%20msdn%20enter&ei=uV3kTN_FFoPusgat0ZCfBA&usg=AFQjCNFs-cyTNnL6uYI95Xu3uKSA867LUQ&sig2=rloNUXwjuBKnxGirNNTR3w&cad=rja) on the Form or a Panel. This way you have full control what happens.
- Set [UseSubmitBehavior](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx&rct=j&q=asp.net%20UseSubmitBehavior&ei=jF3kTN7DKY_6sgaH44DsCw&usg=AFQjCNHxfCWvxIlAAzNMpnIJzZKF-it9RA&sig2=HZZ5bldRmjXhGxt4D3iVnw&cad=rja)="False" on your Buttons. This disables the "AutoPostback" on Enter.

I would prefer the second if i wanted to prevent Postbacks on Enter completely.

Comment: If its an imagebutton .. whats the solution.??

Comment: @SRJ: you could use an `Image` instead. Or have a look at this question which addresses that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561400/how-to-disable-submit-behaviour-of-aspimagebutton

Comment: Using the "<asp:Panel>" and the button's attribute "UseSubmitBehavior" to false was my solution for a similar issue.  Here's this bit of the source: https://pastebin.com/9hXJBrmk

Answer (score 29):

are you using jQuery?

if so:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode === 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that stop the enter key from inserting a blank line in textarea?

Comment: It would also stop the submit behavior on enter press when the focus is in that textbox where the enter press should invoke the submit (`i.e username/password textbox`)

Comment: Great solution. @sohaiby @Tony_Henrich  It is easy to replace `document` to a selector that targets exactly those inputs where the Enter key should be suppressed. It is also easy, however pointless, to circumvent jQuery by using plain JS.

Answer (score 9):

Use the below code to disable enter key causing postback. This piece of code will block the enter key in all browsers 4.0 above, except when enter is pressed in a Textarea or on the Submit button itself.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var nav = window.Event ? true : false;
if (nav) {
window.captureEvents(Event.KEYDOWN);
window.onkeydown = NetscapeEventHandler_KeyDown;
} else {
document.onkeydown = MicrosoftEventHandler_KeyDown;
}

function NetscapeEventHandler_KeyDown(e) {
if (e.which == 13 && e.target.type != 'textarea' && e.target.type != 'submit') { 
return false; 
}
return true;
}

function MicrosoftEventHandler_KeyDown() {
if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.srcElement.type != 'textarea' && 
event.srcElement.type!= 'submit')
return false;
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I've attempted to use so many different javascript event handlers to cancel an asp form submit on Enter, but none of them work as well as this one. I can event change the "return false;" lines to another javascript method to always have Enter submit the data I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Only put this on you ASP.Net TextBox control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
   onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);" >
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is default behavior of a web application, you could take one of the tutorials that you found and hide that behavior, by simply abandoning the submit.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13)">
```