# button event accidentally occured after textchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, textbox, textchanged

I have a problem with textchanged event on textbox.
After i input some string and hit enter, i don't know why button click is fired too

here my .aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
    <asp:Label ID="labelKodeDivisi" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 62px; top: 57px; position: absolute" Text="labelKodeDivisi"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="labelNamaDivisi" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 62px; top: 85px; position: absolute" Text="labelNamaDivisi"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="butLogout" runat="server" OnClick="butLogout_Click" style="z-index: 1; left: 682px; top: 40px; position: absolute" Text="Button" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbKode" runat="server" OnTextChanged="tbKode_TextChanged" style="z-index: 1; left: 71px; top: 127px; position: absolute"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

and here my aspx.cs

```
public partial class FormDivisi2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void butLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelKodeDivisi.Text = "123";
    }

    protected void tbKode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelNamaDivisi.Text = "555";
    }
}
```

Whats going on is, when i input text in textbox tbKode and hit enter, labelNamaDivisi.text change to 555 but labelKodeDivisi.text also change to 555.
What i want is when i input some text in textbox tbKode, labelNamaDivisi.text change to 555 but labelKodeDivisi not change. labelKodeDivisi only change when i hit button butLogout

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209903/asp-net-page-enter-key-causing-post-back

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$('input').keypress(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode==13)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            }
        })
```