# ASP.NET Webforms OnClientClick without enter submission

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have the following command button:

```
<asp:Button Text="Insert Value" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Confirmation.value('insert');" CommandName="Insert" />
```

I am using `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` to prevent [ASP.Net page enter key causing post back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209903/asp-net-page-enter-key-causing-post-back)

I do not want to listen to the enter keyCode via javascript because enter is used to submit non-webform elements not related to the form

Apparently, when using a `Command` and  `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` then `OnClientClick` doesnt work. If I turn on submit behavior it works as expected but then hitting enter on the page automatically tries to click the button.

I prefer not to listen for the click event in Jquery or in javascript, and prefer a webform solution. Possible a better way of prevent enter from submitting the form or a way for OnClientClick  to work properly with no submit behavior

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use Panel and keep all your form inside Panel Tag and set the DefaultButton value of Panel to Button. Like Below:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">

         // other form elements

       <asp:Button Text="Insert Value" ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Confirmation.value('insert');" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Thats the issue, I dont want there to be a defaultButton. I want nothing webforms to enter binding.