# how to disable auto postback when I select the date in calendar in asp.net(C# web form)

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I select date in web application which created by C# asp.net, the page refresh and scroll goes to the top of the page. I want to avoid this auto postback option, so I searched several articles, but could not get the answer.

There is no "autopostback" option to disable refresh. Also, SelectionChanged method was not working. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome Daniel https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please check this article on how to ask a good question. It helps if you supply code so we can see why your UI is doing a post back then we can advise how to stop it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net page enter key causing post back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209903/asp-net-page-enter-key-causing-post-back)