# How to prevent the enter button from clicking a control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net, I have a text edit control, and when I press enter, it clicks some button I have which isn't related to the text edit control.

Is there a way to disable the enter key for the text edit control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's WebForms, you could use something like `onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);"` in your asp:TextBox.

Full example:

`<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);">`

This answer is coming from: [disabling default button or enter key in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934223/disabling-default-button-or-enter-key-in-asp-net-c-sharp)