# When I press enterkey on textbox than page_load twice(google chrome)

Tags: asp.net

I want do textbox_textchanged,but when i press enter key,it will do postback twice,and in my project is Serious error.It will overwrite my error message.I hope let user use textchanged,also user press enterkey can do textchanged event.
When i user google chrome i have this problem,but IE isn't have this porblem.
it's example this's my aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lbl1.Text = "first load";
    }
    else
    {
        lbl1.Text = "postback=>> ispostback";
    }
}

    protected void ttbtest_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl4.Text = "YOU DO ttbtest_TEXTCHANGED，YOU KEY IN：" + ttbtest.Text;
}
```

my aspx example:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function txtTextKeyDown(txt) {
            if ((window.event.keyCode == 13) && txt.value != '') {
                __doPostBack("ttbtest", "TextChanged");
            }
            else return;
        }
        function ConvertFindEnterKey() {
            if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
                var readcode = event.srcElement.value;
                __doPostBack("ttbtest", "TextChanged");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox onkeypress="javascript:return ConvertFindEnterKey();" ID="ttbtest" runat="server"
                            Width="250px" CssClass="CSInput" MaxLength="30" OnTextChanged="ttbtest_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl4" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: I think the error is here : `if ((window.event.keyCode == 13) && txt.value != '') {` change it to `if ((window.event.keyCode != 13) && txt.value != '') {`

Comment: Enter key by default will result in the button in markup that follows the textbox being clicked. So if you have the textbox trigger a post back then the post back for text box + any button that follows after the text box will also trigger (check out the event for any button that follows the textbox - it's going to get trigger if you hit enter key

Comment: @Aristos thank you for help , but is also postback twice ;(

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal yes, If I discard autopostback="true", i can fix it when i press enter key than postback twice , but ontextchanged doesn't work

Comment: As I careful pointed out, ANY input button (and that includes even those in a grid, or any other button) WILL BE triggered. So, you can put in a dummy button (with style = display:none, and usesubmit behavior = none right at the start of your markup to thwart this behavior that all pages will experience. see this for the explain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934223/disabling-default-button-or-enter-key-in-asp-net-c-sharp